# Java serial port write/send ASCII data

Tags: java, matlab, serial-port

My problem is that I need to control mobile robot E-puck via Bluetooth in Java, by sending it commands like "D,100,100" to set speed, "E"  to get speed, and etc. I have some code:

```
String command = "D,100,100";
OutputStream mOutputToPort = serialPort.getOutputStream();
mOutputToPort.write(command.getBytes());
```

So with this method `write` I can only send `byte[]` data, but my robot won't understand that.
For example previously I have been using this commands on Matlab like that:

```
s = serial('COM45');
fopen(s);
fprintf(s,'D,100,100','async');
```

Or on program Putty type only:

```
D,100,100 `enter`
```

**Additional info:**

I've also figured out, that Matlab has another solution for same thing.

```
s = serial('COM45');
fopen(s);
data=[typecast(int8('-D'),'int8') typecast(int16(500),'int8') typecast(int16(500),'int8')];
```

In this case:

```
data = [  -68  -12    1  -12    1];
fwrite(s,data,'int8','async');
```

Wouldn't it be the same in Java:

```
  byte data[] = new byte[5];
  data[0] = -'D';
  data[1] = (byte)(500 & 0xFF);
  data[2] = (byte)(500 >> 8);
  data[3] = (byte)(500 & 0xFF);
  data[4] = (byte)(500>> 8);
```

And then:

```
OutputStream mOutputToPort = serialPort.getOutputStream();
mOutputToPort.write(data);
mOutputToPort.flush();
```

Comment: it's all bytes eventually.  how are you generating the bytes?

Comment: byte[] is the only thing that ANYTHING understands, I don't see your problem. Maybe be more specific.

Comment: This is the best advice I can give you with the information you have given:  Check the endianness of the robot.

Comment: What you just described you were doing in Matlab and in putty, is identical to the code you posted. Also, make sure you flush the outputstream.

Comment: It's identical but it doesn't work for some reason. Yes, I am using flush method.

Comment: Java uses default encoding with getbytes. Maybe use have UTF-16 or Some non ASCII ?

Comment: @RobAu, I'll bet that is it. specify Utf-8, java by default uses 16 bit characters.

Comment: I have tried to change to UTF-8, still the result was the same.

Comment: Can you look in the documentation of your robot and tell us what the endianness (byte-ordering) of the cpu is?

Comment: Sorry, but all I can find for now is the microchip name: dsPIC 30F6014A

Comment: Try calling `mOutputToPort.flush();` after writing the bytes.  Or try adding a newline character to the end of the string `"D,100,100\n"`.  Or both.

Comment: Matlab is sending little endian unless you tell it otherwise while JAVA always uses BigEndian. I'd be willing to bet that is your problem.

Comment: Convert your byte[] to little endian and then send it. Working on a code example right now.

Comment: @emcsIV, I don't know if this is your issue or not, but it is worth a try. See my updated answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time. I won't be able to try it right now, so I will replay latter, if anyone faces with the same problem..

Comment: @JonathanHenson - endianness is irrelevant when sending single byte values.  the use of ByteBuffer in the current code is both unnecessary and useless (as it doesn't actually do anything the way it is currently written).

Comment: Please check my question section -  Additional 2013-11-25, tell me why  similar code with Matlab works and with Java doesn't?

Comment: @Mike Clark your suggestion about new line `"\n"`, was a good starting point to solve the problem. It was all about how different languages add one code after another. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @emcsIV Glad to hear it.  If you solved your problem, consider posting the solution and marking your answer as the accepted answer.  It is OK to answer your own questions on SO, and accept those answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main details in code comments. Now you can change wheel speed by typing in command window `D,1000,-500` and hitting enter.

```
public class serialRobot {

        public static void main(String[] s) {
                SerialPort serialPort = null;
                try {
                        CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM71");
                        if (portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned()) {
                                System.out.println("Port in use!");
                        } else {
                                System.out.println(portIdentifier.getName());

                                serialPort = (SerialPort) portIdentifier.open(
                                                "ListPortClass", 300);
                                int b = serialPort.getBaudRate();
                                System.out.println(Integer.toString(b));
                                serialPort.setSerialPortParams(115200, SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                                                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                                serialPort.setInputBufferSize(65536);
                                serialPort.setOutputBufferSize(4096);

                                System.out.println("Opened " + portIdentifier.getName());

                                OutputStream mOutputToPort = serialPort.getOutputStream();
                                InputStream mInputFromPort = serialPort.getInputStream();


                                PerpetualThread t = readAndPrint(mInputFromPort);

                                inputAndSend(mOutputToPort);


                                t.stopRunning();

                                mOutputToPort.close();
                                mInputFromPort.close();
                        }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                        System.out.println("IOException : " + ex.getMessage());
                } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException ex) {
                        System.out.println("UnsupportedCommOperationException : " + ex.getMessage());
                } catch (NoSuchPortException ex) {
                        System.out.println("NoSuchPortException : " + ex.getMessage());
                } catch (PortInUseException ex) {
                        System.out.println("PortInUseException : " + ex.getMessage());
                } finally {
                        if(serialPort != null) {
                                serialPort.close();
                        }
                }

        }

        private static PerpetualThread readAndPrint(InputStream in) {
                final BufferedInputStream b = new BufferedInputStream(in);
                PerpetualThread thread = new PerpetualThread() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                byte[] data = new byte[16];
                                int len = 0;
                                for(;isRunning();) {
                                        try {
                                                len = b.read(data);
                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        if(len > 0) {
                                                System.out.print(new String(data, 0, len));
                                        }
                                }
                        }

                };

                thread.start();

                return thread;
        }

        private static void inputAndSend(OutputStream out) {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                int k = 0;
                for(;;) {

                        String komanda;
                        try {
                                komanda = in.readLine();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                return;
                        }
                        komanda = komanda.trim();

                        if(komanda.equalsIgnoreCase("end"))       return;

                        byte komandaSiust[] = proces(komanda); //Command we send after first 

//connection, it's byte array where 0 member is the letter that describes type of command, next two members 

// is about left wheel speed, and the last two - right wheel speed.



                        try {
                               if(k == 0){
                                String siunc = "P,0,0\n"; // This command must be sent first time, when robot is connected, otherwise other commands won't work
                                ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(siunc.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                                bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
                                out.write(bb.array());
                                out.flush();      
                               }else{
                               ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(komandaSiust);
                               bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
                               out.write(bb.array());
                               out.flush();
                               }
                               k++;

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                return;
                        }
                }
        }

        private static byte[] proces(String tekstas){
            tekstas = tekstas.trim();
            char[] charArray = tekstas.toCharArray();
            byte kodas1[];



            int fComa = tekstas.indexOf(',', 1);
            int sComa = tekstas.indexOf(',', 2);
            int matavimas = charArray.length;
            int skir1 = sComa - fComa - 1;
            int skir2 = matavimas - sComa -1;

            char leftSpeed[] = new char[skir1];

            for(int i = 0; i < skir1; i++){
                  leftSpeed[i] = charArray[fComa + i + 1];
            }

            char rightSpeed[] = new char[skir2];

            for(int i = 0; i < skir2; i++){
                rightSpeed[i] = charArray[sComa + i + 1];
            }
            String right = String.valueOf(rightSpeed);
            String left = String.valueOf(leftSpeed);


            int val1 = Integer.parseInt(left);
            int val2 = Integer.parseInt(right);
            kodas1 = new byte[5];
            kodas1[0] = (byte)-charArray[0];
            kodas1[1] = (byte)(val1 & 0xFF);
            kodas1[2] = (byte)(val1 >> 8);
            kodas1[3] = (byte)(val2 & 0xFF);
            kodas1[4] = (byte)(val2 >> 8);

            return kodas1;


        }

        private static class PerpetualThread extends Thread {
                private boolean isRunning = true;

                public boolean isRunning() {    return isRunning;       }

                public void stopRunning()       {
                        isRunning = false;
                        this.interrupt();
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/javacomm/reference/api/javax/comm/SerialPort.html), you need to call `setSerialPortParams(int baudrate, int dataBits, int stopBits, int parity)` on your serial port.

Comment: In matlab I've found connection params:
comPort = serial(port,'BaudRate', 115200,'inputBuffersize',65536,'OutputBufferSize',4096,'ByteOrder','littleendian');
maybe I can set the same on serial port with Java?

Comment: @emcsIV You can, those settings need to match exactly what the spec says.

Comment: Please look at my question - Additional 2013-11-25. I have provided Matlab code and similar Java code I wrote, but still with Java doesn't work.

Comment: @emcsIV did you try my recent update? My answer is attempting to answer why your java code doesn't work.

Comment: @ Jonathan Henson maybe there is a program that could show me what data com port receives when I am using one or another code?