# Serial port, how to read what you sent to device?

Tags: java, serial-port

I want to see what binary code is coming to device connected to serial port, while I am sending same binary code with Java and Matlab. But as we know I can not connect two programs to same port at the same time.

This is all about because I can't find why my program isn't working it's my last chance to see the deference. Main problem here: 
[Serial commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154406/java-serial-port-write-send-ascii-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the tools at [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net) to connect multiple applications to the same virtual COM port. This way, you can send on what looks like a serial port, and access the data from many programs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a company called [Frontline](http://www.fte.com/default.aspx) that sells software and cables that enable you to "listen in" on serial communication without interfering with the communication itself.  It is very comprehensive and powerful but expensive.  I bought it a few years back for $700.  It comes standard with cables for detecting rs232 communication but with some know how you can make your own cables for monitoring other serial formats as well.  Keep in mind that it requires 2 spare rs232 ports in addition to the ports you are trying to monitor.